# What comics share a universe with Invincible?

Tags: comics, shared-universe, robert-kirkman, invincible

In the letters page of a recent issue of Super Dinosaur, Robert Kirkman (or possible Sina Grace) stated the idea that Super Dinosaur is in it's own universe as much as The Walking Dead is (in reference to Invincible's universe).

Because of the nature of Image's creator-owned content, there has historically been some goofiness around what comics share a universe. However, because Robert Kirkman has been involved in a fairly large number of comics in recent years, he's had the capability to establish a shared universe (mostly around Invincible).

Some have been made explicitly clear - characters from Guarding the Globe, Brit, Tech Jacket, and The Astounding Wolf-Man show up in Invincible and vice versa. Others star cameos from Invincible-universe characters in their own series (e.g. Savage Dragon). Then there's Image United, which features numerous characters from Image and Top Cow titles.

Is there a canon for what titles share a universe and what do not? It sounds like Super Dinosaur and The Walking Dead definitely aren't in the shared universe, and I'm fairly sure Image United isn't canon to *anybody.*

Answer (score 5):

**[Skybound Entertainment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skybound_Entertainment) is the imprint/sister company that Robert Kirkman publishes his properties which were created while he was a partner at Image Comics. Skybound is currently the home of Invincible and a number of other Kirkman projects.**

There are a number of other projects being created at Skybound but it is unclear how porous the dimensional barriers will be in their new home.

- Their current line-up includes: Invincible, Tech Jacket, Thief of Thieves, The Walking Dead, Witch Doctor, The infinite, Cloudfall, Brit, Battle Pople and the Astounding Wolf-Man.
- Image tended to separate its comic characters via dimensional barriers. This allowed them to share a multiverse (making team-ups possible, but unlikely).
- Unless otherwise specified most characters exist within their own dimensional realm separate from other characters. There is a complete character listing of all characters who have interacted with Invincible.

The [Official Handbook to the Invincible Universe](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1582408319) (2006) listed a complete cast of characters who were considered canon to the Invincible Universe.

[image]

### Cast of Characters

- [Non-superpowered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invincible_%28comics%29#Non-superpowered)
- [Superpowered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invincible_%28comics%29#Superheroes)
- [Enemies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invincible_%28comics%29#Enemies)

### Continuity

> - Invincible, along with Firebreather and other new Image superhero characters, debuted in an issue of The Savage Dragon, and has since appeared with several of the characters in The Pact mini-series.
>
>   - Robert Kirkman wrote a miniseries, Savage Dragon: God War and two Superpatriot mini-series, establishing the friendship between Superpatriot's wife Claire and Invincible's mother in the pages of Invincible #13 and later.
>   - The Savage Dragon connection is mostly downplayed and Invincible follows its own continuity, tied mainly with previously mentioned satellite Kirkman characters. Invincible also appeared in the fourth issue of Jay Faerber's Noble Causes, and was seen at the funeral for Captain Dynamo, father of the characters in Faerber's Dynamo 5.
>   - Similarly, Invincible #48 features cameo appearances from several Savage Dragon characters, as well as both Dynamo 5, and many of Kirkman's own creations, while an earlier issue featured a funeral for the Guardians of the Globe, at which many Image characters, including Savage Dragon and Jack Staff, were in attendance.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've read, it seems that there is no set canon of what does and does not share a universe, especially among Kirkman's work. In the past, they have been inconsistent with referencing other titles. Sometimes the references don't make much sense, but Image seems to cross titles in more of an easter egg way than an actual crossover.

Answer (score 1):

Spawn appears in *[Invincible: Invincible War](https://imagecomics.fandom.com/wiki/Invincible:_Invincible_War)* along with Pitt, the Youngblood team, Witchblade and many others, connecting them all to the same universe. One version of Mark even remarks to Spawn that he killed him in his dimension, and would do it again.

Answer (score 0):

The Astounding Wolf-Man, Brit, Capes, Guarding the Globe, Invincible Presents: Atom Eve & Rex Splode, Invincible Universe, SuperPatriot: America's Fighting Force/War on Terror, Tech Jacket, and Science Dog.

Comment: Can you confirm how you came up with this list?

Comment: FWIW, I recognize all of those titles as being names of characters who have shown up in the series, but Thaddeus's answer is of course superior.